# Not able to get integer value from entry field

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I was trying to create a stock managing program as follows:

```
import mysql.connector as mc
from tkinter import*
import time
from datetime import date  
mycon=mc.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="1234",database="stock_manager")
cursor=mycon.cursor()

global stock_name
global stock_unit_price
global stocks_bought


def add():
    global stock_name
    global stock_unit_price
    global stocks_bought

stock_name_label=Label(root,text="Enter Stock Name")

stock_name_entry=Entry(root,width=50)

stock_unit_price_label=Label(root,text="Enter unit price of stock")

stock_unit_price_entry=Entry(root,width=50)

stocks_bought_label=Label(root,text="Enter number of stocks bought: ")

stocks_bought_entry=Entry(root,width=50)

stock_name=stock_name_entry.get()

stock_unit_price=int(float(stock_unit_price_entry.get()))

stocks_bought=int(stocks_bought_entry.get())


stock_name_label.grid(row=2,column=0)

stock_name_entry.grid(row=3,column=0)

stock_unit_price_label.grid(row=4,column=0)

stock_unit_price_entry.grid(row=5,column=0)

stocks_bought_label.grid(row=6,column=0)

stocks_bought_entry.grid(row=7,column=0)


submit_stock_button=Button(root,text="Submit",command=submit)

submit_stock_button.grid(row=8,column=1)

def submit():
    global stock_name
    global stock_unit_price
    global stocks_bought

submitted_label=Label(root,text="Submitted!")
total_investment=(stock_unit_price)*(stocks_bought)
date=date.today()
cursor.execute("insert into 
all_stocks values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"%(stock_name,stock_unit_price,stocks_bought,total_investment,date))
submitted_label.grid(row=9,column=1)



root=Tk()
title_label=Label(root,text="All Investments") 
add_stock_button=Button(root,text="Add Stock",command=add)
title_label.grid(row=0,column=1) 
add_stock_button.grid(row=1,column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

So what this program is supposed to do is let the user add a stock by clicking the button "add stock". It then reveals the entry fields as given in the add() function defined at the top. After inputting all the information, the user clicks submit. The program then sends a query to update a mysql database with the given information.

My problem is that I need "stock_unit_price" as float and "stocks_bought" as int so that the query is successful. But it appears that the entry field is giving a string value.

I tried converting the string into int like:

```
int('5.0')
```

And even tried like:

```
int(float('5.0'))
```

But nothing works. Pls help

Answer (score 1):

You are using it wrongly .You cant get and assign at same time. I will suggest you to use `StringVar` . Please check the snippet

[image: Stringvar]

```
import tkinter as tk   
root=tk.Tk() 
root.geometry("300x100") 

sk=tk.StringVar() 
sb=tk.StringVar() 

def Add():  
    stock_entry=int(stock_unit_price_entry.get()) 
    stock_bought=int(stocks_bought_entry.get())
    print(stock_entry+stock_bought)   
    sk.set("") 
    sb.set("") 
      

stock_name_label = tk.Label(root,text = 'Enter unit price of stock') 
stock_unit_price_entry = tk.Entry(root,textvariable = sk) 

stocks_bought_label = tk.Label(root,text = 'Enter number of stocks bought:', ) 
stocks_bought_entry=tk.Entry(root, textvariable = sb) 

submit_stock_button=tk.Button(root,text = 'Submit', command = Add) 
   
stock_name_label.grid(row=0,column=0) 
stock_unit_price_entry.grid(row=0,column=1) 
stocks_bought_label.grid(row=1,column=0) 
stocks_bought_entry.grid(row=1,column=1) 
submit_stock_button.grid(row=2,column=1) 
   
root.mainloop()
```

You will get integer as output

Or if you want to go by your method, you have to store your get value which is converted into integer in another variable and then you can use it.

```
stock_unit_price_entry=Entry(root,width=50)
stocks_bought_entry=Entry(root,width=50)
stock_unit=int(stock_unit_price_entry.get())
stock_bought=int(stocks_bought_entry.get())
print(stock_unit)
print(stock_bought)
```

This will also produce same integer output

Comment: IntVar is not supporting arithmetic operations...i also tried putting the converted values in a different variable  but that doesn't work either. I don't see the changes you have made in the code.

Comment: @SumathiIyengar Dont know why it didnt work for you. I have updated my answer with sample addition program.. Please check it out